# BIOS exits 1 beep (indicating DRAM refresh failure) but both RAM seem ok, windows is woking fine

Tags: windows-8, memory, motherboard, bios, dram

I am trying to get into the boot menu of my pc to set up a Linux distribution. But every time I press DEL, I get 1 loud beep and my screen shows nothing.
My BIOS is provided by American Megatrends inc. (P1.90, last updated 04.12.2012) and with their bios, 1 beep seems to indicate a DRAM refresh failure (https://www.acs.edu.au/info/computers/computer-servicing/bios-beep-codes.aspx).

But the odd thing is: I have two RAM with 8GB built-in. I tried removing one of them and starting the pc again. Same thing happened. I tried inserting the first one and removing the other one and restart again. Same thing happened.

Also, I have a running Windows copy on this pc and it works perfectly fine without any errors.

I am inclined to think, that the RAM might not be the problem after all, which leaves me clueless about how to proceed. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure about F2? Some BIOSes require pressing F1, others F2 or F8 or F10. I have also seen wierd BIOSes that require Delete key to be pressed or some combination, like Ctrl+F2. Do you have instruction on screen during startup that indicates exact requirement for pressing F2?

Comment: Some use FN+F2, some Lenovo models use a dedicated button, etc. etc. etc. You need to consult your user's manual and/or online resources, NOT GUESS which one is it.

Comment: I have no instructions whatsoever, but I remember distinctly that F2 once worked on that pc and i have tried every other key you suggested. None of them do anything except F2. All the other keys just start windows without showing the bios

Comment: but maybe me not getting any instructions about how to get into the bios is part of the problem...?

Comment: I'm sure you can find the user's manual online very easy, some for any computer from ~2012

Comment: The manual states that I should press the DEL-Key, which does exactly the same as pressing the F2-Key as described above :/ It beeps once, doesn't show anything on the screen and then stays that way

Comment: Maybe you need to spam the key immediately after powering on. The beep, unlike what you think, actually suggests you're pressing and keeping it and it's causing an overflow. If it's a new UEFI (the replacement for BIOS tha many to this day still call it wrongly "BIOS"), not likely (but possible) giving its age, you could also set Windows to boot into the UEFI ("BIOS") settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but I want to help.

Some PCs beep when you successfully get into BIOS setup or the boot menu.

It is possible that when you pressed DEL or F2, and the PC beeped, you *did* get into BIOS Setup. You just *couldn't see it*. Why? Because on some PCs the BIOS Setup screen is only displayed on certain video ports.

Try to connect your monitor to the other video outputs you might have. If you have a discrete video card as well as onboard video, try the onboard's ports. Try them all if you can.

**Edit...**

I'm struggling to understand the downvote. One of the most common reasons why BIOS Setup doesn't seem to appear is because the PC doesn't output it to all the video ports. I've had PCs that do exactly that. I have edited my answer to make it better.

**References...**

> I cannot see the post screen or get into the BIOS when using displayport. The monitor shows a black screen until it boots into Windows.
> https://linustechtips.com/topic/663941-post-screenbios-doesnt-display-with-displayport/

> I configured my DELL monitor to receive an HDMI signal, rebooted my PC and pressed F2 during the boot process but nothing appeared on the screen.
> https://forums.evga.com/HDMI-connected-screen-does-not-show-BIOS-m2228762.aspx

Comment: I tried it with both HDMI and VGA. None of them worked...

Comment: @Jere I'm really sorry to hear that. I'm struggling to think of a reason why you can't get into BIOS setup. Even if you had configured a password for BIOS Setup, it should display something asking you for said password. You may want to look at "resetting" your BIOS configuration via a jumper or button on the motherboard. Of course, doing that, you'll need to reconfigure your BIOS (if you can get into it!) if you had previously made any changes